# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: .algolia.net (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, laravel, package, algolia

I'm using Bagisto Laravel and when I try to save the product I face this error every time. Any suggestions how can I overcome this error

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is because of your host that your host dont access to algolia.net.

Try on another host.

Comment: could you please tick as best